# unable to insert json data into postgresql using python

Tags: python, json, postgresql

I'm unable to insert the json data below into the postgres db using python. I'm posting the entire code here. PLease let me know why I'm unable to update the data.

**json data to insert:**

```
{"data":"\n\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit's, we're sed'tu do\n=====\nWe'll  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse c",
"data2":"\n\n===========\n\n Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor\nWe'll  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis\nWe'll  nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse c \n\n===========\n\n"
}
```

**Code:**

```
import sys, getopt
import csv
import json
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs


def insert_data(entry):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database = "example", user = "postgres", password = "", host = "127.0.0.1", port = "5432")
    print "Opened database successfully"
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO example (column2) VALUES '{0}'".format(info))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()



i=0
with open("test.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for r in data:
        print json.dumps(data[i])
        dd=json.dumps(data[i])
        insert_data(dd)
        i=i+1
```

I'm getting this error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near \nWe'll
```

Comment: Try `cur.execute("INSERT INTO example (column2) VALUES (%s)", (entry,))` But it seems that your code contains some other errors...

Comment: It doesn't work. The error has is in the json and also at the insert

Comment: Works for me: https://pastebin.com/Faqwg0SD Also it is not obvious what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Can you try it again. I'm still getting the error at \nWe'll

Comment: Yes, it works again and again :o) Your original code contains errors: `KeyError: 0` at `print json.dumps(data[i])` and after the fixing `NameError: global name 'info' is not defined` at `cur.execute("INSERT INTO example (column2) VALUES '{0}'".format(info))` So it seems that you provided not that code where you got the mentioned exception. If it is still actual: 1) `insert...values(...)` - values should be parenthesized; 2) `.format()` function does not quoting special characters like quote `'`, so `"select '{0}'".format("a'b");` will provide `select 'a'b';` what is obviously wrong. Have luck.